# Mongoid not pushing new document into has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have a User class used by Devise that has the following relationship

```
class User
  has_many :listings, dependent: :delete
  has_many :favorites, :class_name => 'Listing', as: :favorites, dependent: :delete
```

And a listing class

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorites, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :favorites
```

I can push `current_user.listings << listing` but I am unable to push `current_user.favorites << listing`

The push seems to be fine, no errors are thrown, but when I ask for current_user.favorites I get 0 results.

I'm wondering if I've set this relationship properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

You need to add a new model called `Favorite` and contains 2 fields: `listing_id` and `user_id` because the relation between users and favorites is many to many.

Or, you need to change the type of favorites in `Listing` model to `Array` like this way:

`field :favorites, type: Array`

Also, remove `has_many :favorites ...` in `User` model and add a getter method:

```
def favorites
  Listing.where(favorites: self.id)
end
```

and a setter method:

```
def favorites=(listing)
  Listing.find(listing.id).add_to_set(favorites: self.id)
end
```

Comment: I've tried that out. The `current_user.listings` and current_user.favorites` now both return the same results.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Listing I'd like just to take care of the listings the user created and favourites the listings they like.

Comment: you need to add a new model called `favorites` and it has 2 fields `listing_id` and `user_id` because the relation between users and favorites is many to many

Comment: OR, you need to change the type of `favorites` in listing model to `Array` like this way: `field :favorites, type: Array`. also, remove `has_many :favorites` in user model and add getter method: `def favorites then Listing.where(favorites: self.id) end`, setter method: `def favorites=(listing) then Listing.find(listing.id).add_to_set(favorites: self.id) end`

Comment: I like the idea of letting the Listing documents hold the favorite relationships. I'll try that out.

Comment: Worked out well. Thanks man. Did you want to update your answer and I'll mark it correct?